# Symfony Server Log Level / more verbose?

Tags: php, symfony, logging, server

when I start the symfony server like this:

```
php app/console server:run --docroot=www
```

every error is logged into the dev.log. But I want it instead to be shown on the console. I think that this must be possible, but I don't find it in the documentation..

Comment: `tail -f app/logs/dev*`

Comment: `php app/console server:run -vvv` ?

Comment: ah! -vvv was what i was looking for! thanks!

Comment: @scoolnico you saved my life today !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

php app/console server:run -vvv it was!

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that by adding `-vvv` to the command.

You need to do it by tailing `app/logs/dev.log` with `tail -f file` or `less +F file`